# How do we eliminate 1.5mb of subversion switch noise?

Tags: svn, version-control

Suppose we have a `trunk` and a `dev` branch, copied from `trunk` long ago:

```
/trunk
   |
   --->/branches/dev
```

We try to regularly merge `trunk` changes into `branches/dev`. And, when we're ready for a staging and/or production deployment, we merge `branches/dev` into `trunk`.

However, after a recent batch of merges, we've found that switching between `trunk` and `branches/dev` makes a *lot* of updates to files that **should already be identical!** In particular, I was able to monitor an `svn switch` with fiddler: We see about 1.5MB of delta info come through the pipe, and all are some variation of this:

```
<S:open-file name="ViewerConfiguration.aspx.cs" rev="8352">
<D:checked-in><D:href>/svn/TeacherPortal/!svn/ver/6117/branches/dev/Rowland.TeachersPortal/json/ViewerConfiguration.aspx.cs</D:href></D:checked-in>
<S:set-prop name="svn:entry:committed-rev">6117</S:set-prop>
<S:set-prop name="svn:entry:committed-date">2015-10-07T22:39:08.997655Z</S:set-prop>
<S:set-prop name="svn:entry:last-author">jon</S:set-prop>
<S:set-prop name="svn:entry:uuid">6e396072-32eb-4885-a2ee-922f4ed38072</S:set-prop>
<S:txdelta base-checksum="0feda0fb0cf9b5db99fc1d984ef00b48">U1ZOAQDfGt8aBQEEAN8aAAA=
</S:txdelta><S:prop><V:md5-checksum>0feda0fb0cf9b5db99fc1d984ef00b48</V:md5-checksum></S:prop></S:open-file>
```

The `txtdelta` is absent on most of the files. When it's not, it's always just "SVN".

Diffing these files shows that they are all identical. And comparing the branches show no changes:

```
>svn diff "^/branches/dev" "^/trunk"
Index: .
===================================================================
--- .   (.../branches/dev)      (revision 8357)
+++ .   (.../trunk)     (revision 8357)

Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Modified: svn:mergeinfo
   Reverse-merged /trunk:r5363-8350
   Merged /branches/dev:r5363-8356
```

**The main question is two-fold:**

- At a point when the branches are supposed to be identical (like right now), how can I detect and correct if they're *not* identical?
- How do I eliminate the unnecessary delta information on `svn switch`-es?

And the bonus question:

- What causes this sort of bug?

Comment: You should show logs with mergeinfo and tell what svn server & client version you use. Otherwise the only answer is "that's user error, RTFM".

Comment: @bahrep I don't necessarily disagree that it's user error; but, there's no page in the manual (that I could find) that talks about handling a barrage of meaningless deltas. More importantly, given that I don't already know the solution, I really don't know what logging info to give you. How do I get what you or another subversion expert needs to help me?

Comment: @bahrep I was able to get a little more info... is that helpful?